# What is value of Reverse Saturation Current (Is) for BC547B NPN transistor

Tags: transistors, ebers-moll

I am trying to evaluate Ebers Moll equation for estimating collector current for a given V_BE at DC conditions. The datasheet of BC547B (which I am using) does not mention the Is (i.e. Reverse Saturation Current). Does someone know value of this Is for BC547B? Yes, I know it is of order 10 (-12 or 13). I need more specific value. Thanks.

Comment: The values vary too much from one BJT to another. Perhaps a factor of 3 on either side. Can you tolerate a range of almost an order of magnitude? Because as a practical matter it won't get much more accurate than that.